# CSS transition flickering in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transitions

I have 3 elements that is growing on `:hover` using a CSS transition. Two of them work just fine, but the last one is flickering in Firefox, but works in Chrome and IE. So the problem is only there in Firefox.

**CSS:**

```
.contact{
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 37px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #eca83b;
    border-radius: 10%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.contact:hover{
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 27px;
    height: 260px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="contact">
   <svg> 
   </svg>
   <h2 class="item">Contact</h2>
</section>
```

What can cause this problem?

Comment: I don't see any flickering

Comment: it is best to define wat you are transitioning: `transition: all 0.5s;`, `transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;`, read here what you can define: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had exact same issue: on several sites I've built that use CSS transform scale, there's a flicker the first time you hover over the images. Afterwards they're fine. Doesnt happen on any other browser, and is only recent - obviously a bug in later versions of FF.

Anyway, just fixed it by, of all things, altering the greyscale filter. Try this CSS on your img:

filter: grayscale(1%);

It makes no noticable difference to the colour, but the flicker is gone!

Comment: Actually even adding filter: grayscale(0%); did the trick for me.

Comment: Sadly still having this issue in 2020 with FF 81.  Adding `filter: grayscale(1%)` didn't do anything for me, but it led me on the path to adding something that does work: `filter: blur(0.1px);`

Answer (score 9):

`backface-visibility: hidden` tends to fix a lot of flickering issues, try giving it a shot.

Answer (score 6):

Try putting:

```
will-change: transform;
```

Into your `.contact`

this will pre-render your object into 3d so it should not flicker.

Sometimes it also helps to put it into your class's children, like if you have
`.contact > .img` or something.

Comment: This is THE answer, thanks!  **Note:** the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) says: `will-change is intended to be used as a last resort, in order to try to deal with existing performance problems. It should not be used to anticipate performance problems.`

Answer (score 0):

Add `-moz-transition:` for Firefox i have update in code here 
give this a try it should work

```css
.contact{
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 37px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #eca83b;
    border-radius: 10%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
}

.contact:hover{
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 27px;
    height: 260px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me, however I worked around the issue by setting `visibility:hidden; position: absolute;` on the inactive images and `visibility: visible; position: relative;` on the active one.